# Git rebase strangely adds changes to .gitignore

Tags: git, rebase

I have the following simple test repo (without a `.gitignore`)

Create with https://gist.github.com/gabyx/6ea9cf93e3aaecc9229234ea1f1960fd

```sh
testGitExamples.sh GitTest ex-wrong-committed-files && cd GitTest
```

```sh
Current history is:
 * ec8ddf1 - Added file W (Wrong changes in W.2)  (HEAD -> feature)
 * 8dbb0a8 - Added file D 
 * 54f196a - Added file C 
 * 32834a3 - Added file W (Wrong committed file W.2) 
 * 44a223a - Added file B 
 * 196b079 - Added file A 
 * 9365b59 - Test your solution 
 * f00c3f7 - Init  (master)
```

when I rebase on this repo with

```
git checkout feature
git rebase -i -x 'git rm -r --cache . && git add . && git commit --amend --no-edit' HEAD~4
```

and adding `echo "W.2" > .gitignore` at line 2 in `git-rebase-todo`

```sh
pick 7678be8 Added file W (Wrong committed file)
exec echo "W.2" > .gitignore
exec git rm -r --cache . && git add . && git commit --amend --no-edit
pick ded904f Added file C
exec git rm -r --cache . && git add . && git commit --amend --no-edit
pick dfb4b33 Added file D
exec git rm -r --cache . && git add . && git commit --amend --no-edit
pick 311736d Added file W (Wrong changes)
exec git rm -r --cache . && git add . && git commit --amend --no-edit
```

and doing `git rebase --continue` (which runs successfully through)
git **strangly** adds the changes in the last commit (ec8ddf1) to the `.gitignore`.

What is going on? Is this a bug?

Initial Repo @ https://github.com/gabyx/GitTest

Comment: Do you mean that it adds the `diff` of `ec8ddf1` as text content in `.gitignore`, or what else?

Comment: the .gitignore is part of the repo, so if the other branch has changes in its git ignore they'll get merged in.

Comment: `.gitignore` is a _trackable_ file and there is a revision that is being rebased that has a change on it.

Comment: The diff of `ec8ddf1` gets added as text content yes.
The commit `ec8ddf1` has **absolutely** no diff for the file `.gitignore`

Comment: @eftshift0 Thats not the problem. Its 99% a bug. Test it with git 2.27 and the gist...

Comment: Can you push it somewhere so we can take a look?

Comment: Sure. I can: https://github.com/gabyx/GitTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the contents for `W.2` are the same as the contents of `.gitignore` on the last `pick`, `git`'s rename detection heuristics thinks this was a change to a renamed file (due to their high similarity) and applies the change from `W.2` to `.gitignore`.

This is ultimately caused by the fact that git does not store renames. When you rename a file in `git`, let's say with `git mv`, what gets recorded is a "`File Added, File Deleted`" pair.

Some git operations see this pair and if their contents is similar (above a threshold you can optionally configure with `--find-renames=`), will treat it as if they were the same file, but renamed.

This not only applies to what `git status` shows you but also to operations like `merge` and `rebase` as demonstrated by your question.

You can ask `rebase` to not perform rename detection by passing `-X no-renames`.

Your `rebase` command would be:

```
git rebase -i -x 'git rm -r --cache . && git add . && git commit --amend --no-edit' -X no-renames HEAD~4
```

This type of mistake is more often encountered in minimal working examples as git does not have enough context to make the correct guess.

Comment: Thanks for this very elaborate answer!